# Не возвращает измененную строку

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день. Нужно заменить одни символы в строке на другие. Однако возвращается строка в изначальном состоянии. Почему так?

```
text = '"><br><b>oh no!</b>'
def escape_html(s):
        tags_dict = {'>': '&gt;',
                    '<': '&lt;',
                    '"': '&quot;',
                    '&': '&amp;',
                    '/': '&sol;'}
        keys = tags_dict.keys()
        for key in keys:
            s.replace(key, tags_dict[key])
        return s
print (escape_html(text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки в python являются неизменяемыми, поэтому функция [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) возвращает изменённую строку, а исходная строка не меняется.

Поэтому надо заменить строчку

```
s.replace(key, tags_dict[key])
```

на

```
s = s.replace(key, tags_dict[key])
```

Comment: больше спасибо!